# ActiveRecord: Get number of inserted rows from custom query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some custom queries using the `LOAD DATA INFILE and INSERT INTO ... SELECT syntax` (for good reason, of course).

Currently, I run these with `MyModelName.connection.execute`. However, I would like to get the number of inserts for keeping track.

When I use `MyModelName.connection.insert_sql`, it always returns 0.

When I use `MyModelName.connection.update_sql`, for an INSERT IGNORE it returns the number of unignored rows, which for the first time is what I want, but on an update with several unmodified entries, it's too low. For a REPLACE this even returns twice the number (I guess it counts 1 for a non-duplicate row and when a duplication exists, it counts 1 for the delete and 1 for the insert part).

Counting the number of lines in my import CSV or running a COUNT request afterwards is possible, but both would take unnecessary time and I hope, MySQL might return something that I can use.

Comment: is there a reason why you're using raw sql?

Comment: There is no query interface for LOAD DATA INFILE as far as I know and I have to insert millions of rows in less than an hour on commodity hardware.